# twitter rss or otherwise get 100 latest tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I want to get the last 100 tweets from my twitter account into php.  I can get 25 from the Rss feed, but no more.

Is their another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/<user_name>.xml?count=200
```

Comment: It works for me with mashable (who have more than 200 tweets). Did you try to test it with an account who has tweeted publicly that many times?

Comment: I just typed it into the address bar, will test again now.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the new search API:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Which would let you create a URL like this:

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:<user_name>&rpp=100

...but, most of these methods will only bring back as many from the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

How about you pull the RSS and store it in a database? Then you can get however many you want. You aren't hitting the RSS on every load are you?

Comment: It still only gets the latest 25...is their a way to get more?  I don't mind storing in a database

Comment: So you get 25 one time, then the next time you get some new ones, etc.

Comment: Just to add....this is just good nettiquette. You definalty want some sort of local storage. Not very nice to hit their API on every page load, which is what it sounds like you're doing.